# Zend_Db_Table_Abstract Loading Joined Models

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

I have a tables named:

client (id, alias)
post (id, subject)
post_client (id, post_id, client_id)

Many clients can be joined to a post.

Using Zend DB Table abstract I have started to build a model, here are the classes:

ORM_Post

```
class ORM_Post extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    protected $_name = 'Post';
    protected $_dependentTables = array('ORM_Post_Client');

}
```

ORM_Client

```
class ORM_Client extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {


    protected $_name = 'Client';
    protected $_dependentTables = array(
        'ORM_Post_Client'
    );
}
```

ORM_Post_Client

```
class ORM_Post_Client extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    protected $_name = 'Post_Client';
    protected $_referenceMap    = array(
        'post' => array(
            'columns'           => 'post_id',
            'refTableClass'     => 'ORM_Post',
            'refColumns'        => 'id'
        ),
        'client' => array(
            'columns'           => 'client_id',
            'refTableClass'     => 'ORM_Post_Client',
            'refColumns'        => 'id'
        )

    );
}
```

What I was hoping todo is call an instance of the Post and then load the clients associated aswell as loading an instance of the client and load all posts associated.

So I did this:

```
    $post = new ORM_Post();
    $results = $post->fetchAll();

    foreach ($results as $key => $result){
        $row = $results->current();
        $client = $row->findDependentRowset('ORM_Post_Client','client');
    }
```

and I get
Reference rule "client" does not reference table ORM_Post

I have battled with this for hours and cannot see where I'm going wrong. Am I to declare the Post_Client joins inside the client and post model also?

**EDIT**

Here is what I was after:

```
    $post = new ORM_Post();
$results = $post->fetchAll();
$return = array();

    foreach ($results as $result){
        $row = $post->find($result->id)->current();
        $return[$result->id] = $row->toArray();
        $return[$result->id]['clients'] = $row->findManyToManyRowset('ORM_Client', 'ORM_Post_Client')->toArray();
}

return $return;
```

Thanks for the advice guys, you put me on the right track

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your  `ORM_Post_Client`  it should be

```
'client' => array(
            'columns'           => 'client_id',
            'refTableClass'     => 'ORM_Client',  //instead of ORM_Post_Client 
            'refColumns'        => 'id'
        )
```

> refTableClass => The class name of the parent table. Use the class
>   name, not the physical name of the SQL table ([documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html))

also i think your loop should be :

```
foreach ($results as $result){
        $row = $results->current();
        $clients = $row->findDependentRowset('ORM_Post_Client','post'); 
  }
```

because you are looking for clients of a post which means that post is your `rule`

(`$row->findDependentRowset($table, [$rule]);`  )

Comment: Thank you for spotting this. However it doesn't fix the issue. I get:

Reference rule "client" does not reference table ORM_Post

Answer (score 0):

This as presented won't work, honestly it makes no sense.

```
$post = new ORM_Post();
    $results = $post->fetchAll();

    foreach ($results as $key => $result){
        //$row is assigned to the whole fetchall result!
        $row = $results->current();
        //in this context $client cannot call a dependent rowset.
        $client = $row->findDependentRowset('ORM_Post_Client','client');
    }
```

MMc is correct in that you reference table definition was incorrect however your code has some issues as well. Maybe try something like:

```
 $post = new ORM_Post();

    $results = $post->fetchAll();

    //unless your are going to use the 'key' for something you don't need it
    foreach ($results as $result){

        //you need each row object in order to call findDependentRowset in a one to many relationship.
        $row = $post->find($result->id)->current();
        //unless you have multiple rules set up for each table class pair you don't need to specify the rule.
        $client = $row->findDependentRowset('ORM_Post_Client');
    }
```

Comment: I get a bunch of: 

Notice: Object of class Zend_Db_Table_Row could not be converted to int in /Users/-/Sites/GIT/api/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 853

Comment: @azz0r I made an edit I forgot to specify which property of each result we were looking for. $result->id should work or if the property is not defined $result['id']. where id is the id field of your table. Sorry for the oops.

Comment: This really explained fairly well at http://mattmccormick.ca/2010/04/24/how-to-easily-create-models-and-table-relationships-in-zend-framework/